# why can't i access the docker based zookeeper port

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, jhipster

on OS X i started kafka docker image successfully,but it seems that i can't access it on localhost

```
➜  ~ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                NAMES
1f931da3d661        wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6   "/bin/sh -c '/usr/..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp   docker_zookeeper_1
8bc36bcf8fdf        wurstmeister/kafka:0.10.1.1    "start-kafka.sh"         About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp                               docker_kafka_1
➜  ~ telnet 0.0.0.0:2181
0.0.0.0:2181: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
➜  ~ telnet 0.0.0.0 2181
Trying 0.0.0.0...
telnet: connect to address 0.0.0.0: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
➜  ~ telnet 192.168.43.193 2181
Trying 192.168.43.193...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.43.193: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
➜  ~ telnet 127.0.0.1 2181
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

my docker file is here [kafka.yml](https://github.com/jnuc093/jh-kafka-es-gateway/blob/master/src/main/docker/kafka.yml) and use this command to up:

```
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/kafka.yml up -d
```

when i use

```
./mvnw
```

the console is:

```
2017-09-15 17:05:46.433  WARN 15871 --- [localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
```

how can i access the 2181 port

**EDIT**

docker logs 8bc36bcf8fdf

```
[2017-09-15 08:14:13,386] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
java.lang.RuntimeException: A broker is already registered on the path /brokers/ids/1001. This probably indicates that you either have configured a brokerid that is already in use, or else you have shutdown this broker and restarted it faster than the zookeeper timeout so it appears to be re-registering.
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.registerBrokerInZk(ZkUtils.scala:393)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.registerBrokerInZk(ZkUtils.scala:379)
    at kafka.server.KafkaHealthcheck.register(KafkaHealthcheck.scala:70)
    at kafka.server.KafkaHealthcheck.startup(KafkaHealthcheck.scala:51)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:270)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:39)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2017-09-15 08:14:13,393] INFO [Kafka Server 1001], shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

docker logs 1f931da3d661

```
2017-09-14 08:53:05,878 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@357] - caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15e7ea74c8e0000, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-09-14 08:53:05,887 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1007] - Closed socket connection for client /172.18.0.2:54222 which had sessionid 0x15e7ea74c8e0000
```

Comment: From my point of view it's problem with zookeeper since you are not able to telnet from localhost. Do you need `3.4.6` version? try latest `wurstmeister/zookeeper`. where is `3.4.9` version - https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/zookeeper/~/dockerfile/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using host networking as in this example? https://docs.confluent.io/current/cp-docker-images/docs/quickstart.html#zookeeper

That looks like it will simplify and solve this. I'd also recommend checking out these images instead of the custom ones it looks like you are using because these are being run in production for people so they are known to work well.